# Twitter API from_user replacement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have  rails app and i'm using the twitter gem but I can longer use the from_user method in my view as it was removed in V5.

I just want to create a link so someone can go to that tweet on twitter rather then just displaying the text.

### Controller

```
def tweets
   $client.user_timeline("######", :count => 3)   
end
```

#### View

```
<% tweets.each do |t| %>
    <li><%= link_to t.text, "http://twitter.com/#{t.from_user}" %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's been changed which I don't think it has, the gem will provide you with the url of the tweet.

```
<%= link_to t.text, t.url %>
```